# Click event through on is attaching click event again and again when I click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following html

```
<div class="connect">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Assign a Task</a></li>
                    <li><a attr="viewCard" href="#">View Card</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

And I have written some javascript

```
$MyContacts = function () {

    var attachEvents = function () {
        $("#ContactProfile").on("click", clickedOnContactProfileCard);

    };

    var clickedOnContactProfileCard = function (event) {
        if (event.target.localName.toLowerCase() == "a") {

            var currObj = $(event.target);

            alert(currObj.attr("attr").toLowerCase());
            if (currObj.attr("attr").toLowerCase() === "viewcard") {
                currObj.click(function () {
                    alert("aaa");
                    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                        resizable: false,
                        zIndex: 9999,
                        fontSize: 5,
                        modal: true,
                        height: 300,
                        width: 350,
                        buttons: {
                            "Save": function () { }
                        },
                        Cancel: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        close: function () {

                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    };

    var returnElement = {
        attachEvents: attachEvents
    };

    return returnElement;
}();
```

When I am clicking on "viewCard" link first time it shows only "viewcard" in alert. When I click second time it it shows "aaa" in alert and open the dailog box. When I click third time shows "aaa" in alert two times. When I click third time it shows sometimes "viewcard" in alert then two or three times "aaa" in alert.

Can you please help me where I am doing some mistakes

Comment: "===" is for comparing objects. Use "==" to compare values.

Comment: '===' is for strictly comparison. Also the type has to be the same. : `4 === '4'` returns false. '==' is for loosly comparison: `4 == '4'` gives true. Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Comment: @Diodeus, "===" is not the only problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding events multiple times. Thus you are getting this result. You can use [**.off()**](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove an event handler.

Your immediate solution is

```
currObj.off('click').click(function () {
```

instead of

```
currObj.click(function () {
```

Note: I would also recommend you to use `data-*` prefix attributes

```
<li><a attr="viewCard" href="#">View Card</a></li>
```

Use

```
<li><a data-attr="viewCard" href="#">View Card</a></li>
```

Which can be retrived using [**.data()**](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

---

*But if my control is dynamic then how I can attach event using only .click().*

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

General Syntax

```
$(document).on(event, selector, eventHandler);
```

Ideally you should replace `document` with closest static container.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but I am using $("#ContactProfile").on("click", clickedOnContactProfileCard); I am not attaching event multiple time. "attachEvents" calls only once.

Comment: @SharadKumarSingh, Problem is not there. Problem is that you are binding event in event handler.

Comment: But if my control is dynamic then how I can attach event using only .click(). I have to use .on()

Comment: @SharadKumarSingh Then You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)  General Syntax `$(document).on(event, selector, eventHandler);`

Answer (score 0):

Its #ContactProfile the container of that markup?

I asked that because the reason of the click event stacking can be "event bubbling" which means when you click on "viewCard", its parent #ContactProfile gets clicked too calling again clickedOnContactProfileCard and re-binding the click event on "viewcard".

If im correct, the solution should be adding this line at the end of the currObj click event function

```
currObj.click(function (event) {
   ...
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Note that i also added the event argument

Sorry for the bad english, i hope my answer helps you...